How do I add a new position or a new line to the docs.google API
How do I add a new position or a new line to the docs.google API
Via Google.Apis.Sheets.v4
The range always adds to the first place and I need to get to the last
var oblist = new List<object>() { "value" };
valueRange2.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };
            
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest update = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange2, "1jWi**_xqHQ", "sheet!1:999");
update.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
UpdateValuesResponse result2 = update.Execute();

The value goes into cell A1

Is this your expected output? In the sample, the new values were added in the next row instead of overwriting the first row. If that's the case, you can use the append method instead of update.

I found the answer
    var oblist = new List<object>() { "value" };
valueRange2.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };
            
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest update = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange2, "1jWi**_xqHQ", "sheet!1:999");
update.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
        update.InsertDataOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.INSERTROWS;
AppendValuesResponse result2 = update.Execute();

What I still don't know is to add a new column;
Thanks to Serenity his response helped me
